# how can I make 'string' to an array true

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have

```
const all = ['all', 1, 1, 2]
if('all' == all)
 return all
```

How can I make this if statement true.

Comment: if (all.indexOf('all') > -1) return all

Comment: `'all' === all[0]`?

Comment: `'all' == all || true`?

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you mean by `==`. Do you want it to compare to every element of the array? Just the first?

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve? `if (all.includes("all")) return all`

Comment: Its not right sense to make a statement true forcefully. What we do is we check whether the statement is true or false. That is what conditions do

Comment: You could add this line before the `if` condition: `all['toString'] = function() { return this[0] }`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't modify the exisiting code but you still want the expression be `true`.

You may override the [`[Symbol.toPrimitive]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive) function of the `Array.prototype` to change the default behaviour when an array needs to convert to a primitive(while comparing to a primitive, math operations etc.)

```js
Array.prototype[Symbol.toPrimitive] = function() {
  return this[0];
}

const all = ['all', 1, 1, 2];
console.log('all' == all);
```

But... why whould you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use:

```
if (all.includes("all")){
return all
}
```